# Confused in Activity diagram notation

Tags: uml, diagram, activity-diagram

I have made an activity diagram for gym management, but i am facing a problem how will i connect Receptionist with Admin, According to requirement activity between Admin and receptionist takes place only through notification and i have made a signal and receptor for notification. Please also check if every notation is right and suggest me for modification?
[image: Activity Daigram]

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry for not answering at once - several times had I looked at your picture, and, frightened, retreated.

You really tried and did something. It is good. But... You have put Use Cases directly into the activity diagram. So as is, it has no sense.

Let's take a customer. He has his swimlane. Good. According to your diagram, the customer comes and decides, what to do - immediately leave, join or inquiry. It doesn't matter, if he joins or inquiries, the result is common (why had he been choosing?) - he gives some unknown message to the receptionist. He never gets something back, never he does smth. else, he remains here and becomes immortal, because even his death won't finish his state of being here, waiting for some reaction from anybody. Poor man!

I don't think it is necessary to analyze here other swimlanes - they are even worse.

Better divide your work into levels.

- Use Case diag. Define, who are actors (you have defined them well) and what are their interaction with system and its parts.
- As the next stage you can make a deployment diagram - where are components of the system and maybe, actors, located and what messages they send to each other, defined.
- And only now you can start with Activity diagram.

Also notice, that you'll have to return and correct the elders diagrams when you'll come to a dead end or some radical changes in the younger ones. You'll meet with both, be sure.

And when you have some problem with some diagram, come here, write down what you had BEFORE it (you didn't), what you have done on this stage (you did it) and we'll be able to help.